# Excel named lists, concatenating results

Tags: microsoft-excel, named-ranges

I have created 3 named lists (I have filled a couple of entries out as examples)

```
Instance
--------
Germany
England
France
Italy

VRF-Germany 
-----------
Internal
External
Secret

VRF-NonGermany    
--------------
Internal
External
Restricted
```

What I would like to achieve:

If someone clicks in Column H, they will be presented with a drop down list "Instance".   This I know how to do, easy peasy

The next Column I, the resulting list should be presented based on the following logic

If H = Germany, then present the named list VRF-Germany concenated with the selected Instance ie. "Germany-Internal", "Germany-External" and so on
If H is not Germany, then present the named list VRF-NonGermany concenated with the selected Instance ie. "France-Internal", "Italy-Restricted" and so on

I know that I would have to use offsets, but am totally flumoxed as to how I incorporate the rest of the logic

Any help would be most appreciated

Comment: the term for this is dynamic drop downs or indirect drop downs, see this link, i don't have the time to write out a full answer https://exceljet.net/dependent-dropdown-lists